# Combining Four Different Ranges Effectively

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iterator, dry

### Context

Say I have 4 ranges with four different numbers, A1, A2, B1, B2. I want to perform several operations on the same object, using combinations of those 4 ranges

```py
obj = SomeClass() # SomeClass has a method some_func which manipulates an instance
```

Simply, I would use 4 for-loops

```py
for a, b in zip(range(A1), range(B1)):
    obj.some_func(a, b)

for a, b in zip(range(A2, -1, -1), range(B1)):
    obj.some_func(a, b)

for a, b in zip(range(A1), range(B2, -1, -1)):
    obj.some_func(a, b)

for a, b in zip(range(A2, -1, -1), range(B2, -1, -1)):
    obj.some_func(a, b)
```

### Question

Is there a way to do this with only 1 for-loop? since using 4 for-loops seems redundant since I'm basically doing the same thing.

Comment: Your 4 for-loops won't work, since you can only iterate over a range object once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanted only one `for` loop, you could combine the `zip`s:

```py
def all_pairs(A1, A2, B1, B2):
    yield from zip(range(A1), range(B1))
    yield from zip(range(A2, -1, -1), range(B1))
    yield from zip(range(A1), range(B2, -1, -1))
    yield from zip(range(A2, -1, -1), range(B2, -1, -1))

for a,b in all_pairs(A1, A2, B1, B2):
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: Very interesting post and the use of *yield from*.  *nested generators*.  +1